# How to add restriction in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, ionic3

I'm making an application using ionic 3 and firebase.In this app there is page which will show the items inserted by a particular user (in order to edit it) who is currently log in through his account. But I'm unable to add this functionality. The search bar is functioning perfectly and displaying all the items which are inserted by all the users but unable to add this restriction. 
Need help ! Thanks in advance

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

Simply  when you Signup a user through authentication service of firebase on its response using promise you can get user id  created and saved by firebase in regarding to that registered user and then created a node in firebase db (e.g usersRole) and set the role (admin,user)  on that id and get through that